# Shell script not running with cronjob

Tags: centos, shell-script, cron, cronjob

I am using PUTTY to reach the server. I can dump the databases with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --all-databases | /bin/gzip > Backup_DB/alldatabases_test.sql.gz
```

When I am running the script from root, the file is dumped in the specified folder:

```
root@server1 [~]# sh mybackup.sh
root@server1 [~/Backup_DB]# ls -a
./  ../  alldatabases_test.sql.gz
```

However, when I set this up as a cronjob, it's not dumping anything:

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   sh mybackup.sh
```

Other cronjobs are working fine.

**EDIT**

So running the script is not working, but I appreciate your help.
My ultimate goal is to run the script from a place where all my other cronjobs are and create the backup in a folder I have ftp access to.
That's why I added a cronjob:

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   sh /home/mysite/www/cronjobs/mybackup.sh
```

with the content:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --all-databases | /bin/gzip > /home/mysite/www/cronjobs/alldatabases.sql.gz
```

This is not working either. I couldn't find the alldatabases.sql.gz in the /cronjobs folder. Are the paths set wrong?

Comment: Where is your `mybackup.sh`? Can you try to alter your cronjob to `sh /path/to/mybackup.sh`?

Comment: I am not a linux guy, but when I log in to PUTTY and list the folders I see folders like Desktop, Documents, Downloads,Pictures, public_html etc. This is where mybackup.sh is.

Comment: Ok, when you see `mybackup.sh`. Can you type `pwd` to get the current working directory. Let's say it's `/home/username`, append it with `mybackup.sh`. So, in your cron you can use something like `sh /home/username/mybackup.sh`. Hope this help : )

Comment: It is /root. Should I append the file to that as well?

Comment: Yes, you can try it. `sh /root/mybackup.sh`

Comment: Nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need the full path to the script [as @attomos said](https://superuser.com/a/743896/2259). The easiest way to get this is to run `cd relative/path/to/script/directory` and then `pwd` or `echo "$PWD"` to get the current directory.

Second, the `Backup_DB/alldatabases_test.sql.gz` path inside the script is now *relative to the **system root***, so the script tries to save it to `/Backup_DB/alldatabases_test.sql.gz`, which probably was not intended. You need to **make that path absolute as well**: `/root/Backup_DB/alldatabases_test.sql.gz`.

You should see some error output from this in `/var/log/cron`.

Comment: That didn't help. There is nothing in the log about that script.

Comment: What is the actual line in your crontab right now?

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope this elaborates it.

Comment: You need to use an absolute path for the output file, as I just said. With your latest cron job `alldatabases.sql.gz` will be saved on the system root. The shell redirect operator works on the *current directory*, which at least for a root cron job is going to be the root directory.

Comment: I have added the path. Please see my editet post again. Still no file created in the /cronjobs folder.

Comment: What is the output of `ls /home/mysite/www/cronjobs`?

Comment: Wow. It finally came! And you were right, without the absolute path, a file was created in /home/mysite, however it's not root. Thank you for your help!